# Trigger two build definition with one check in - Continuous Integration TFS

Tags: tfs, build, continuous-integration, gated-checkin

I have two build definition "A" and "B". I marked "A" to be triggered (Gated Check-in) when the check in include files under **"src\ProjectA"**  and "B" to be triggered when the check in include files under **"src\ProjectB"**.
It's working as expected when the chech-in include only one of the folders.

When the **check-in include both of the folder** and I click the CkeckIn button in Visual Studio I have to select which build I want to run (I choose "A") and only this build running and all the files are getting in, **meaning that some code get into the repository that can break the build that didn't run ("B").**

How can I make TFS run both builds whenever such a checkin will be delivered and not accept the change if all of the depended build get passed?

Answer (score 0):

Each gated check-in build definition can have only one running build at a time.  If you have two build definitions configured for the same source control folder then you will **always get a choice**. Your situation is very likely configured for the same source control folder.

It is recommended to have **only check in each Project fold** instead of check in include both of the folder together to avoid confusion. As a workaround you could first check in files in folder `src\ProjectA` and then exclude others, after the gated check-in build completed, include other files again.

For more info of the TFVC gated check-in, you could take a look at *James Reed*'s answer in this question [Can we build multiple gated check-ins in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34780595/can-we-build-multiple-gated-check-ins-in-parallel)